# had been quick to Verb?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure

I just read a sentence:

> Critics have been quick to blame these traders for market disruptions and regularly ________ them of gaming the system.

I don't what *quick* in here mean. And what's the correct way to use

> have been p.p. to Verb

I rarely see this type of usage. Why not just say *"These trader have been ..."*?

Comment: _Quick_ has its usual meaning. People who considered certain traders to be responsible for disruptions in the market _quickly_ began to criticise them for it. I don't understand the rest of your question.

Comment: This question should be closed, because it can be answered by using a dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Be quick to blame" mean "to blame without delay".  It means "quickly".

The sentence has a subject of "critics".  The critics blamed the traders without delay.  You can't rephrase to "These trader have been..." unless you use passive voice.  The passive voice would be possible, but most writers prefer the active. An equivalent passive voice sentence is harder to understand.

Comment: We sometimes use 'quick to...' when we want to suggest a (possibly unfair) tendency to do something, e.g. the boss is quick to blame me when something goes wrong, but happy to take the credit when we have a success.